# A CNN that takes several rows from a CSV file as a single input

Tags: python, csv, conv-neural-network

I have extracted facial features from several videos in the form of facial action units(AU) using an open face. These features span for several seconds and hence take several rows in a CSV file (each row containing AU data for each frame of the video). Originally, I had multiple CSV files as input for CNN but, as advised by others, I have concatenated and condensed the data into a single file. My CSV columns look like this:

```
Filename | Label | the other columns contain AU related data
```

Filename contains individual "ID" that helps keep track of a single "example". The label column contains 2 possible values. Either "yes" or "no". I'm also considering to add a "Frames" column to keep track of frame number for a certain "example".

The most likely scenario is that I will require some form of a 3DCNN but so far, the only codes or help that I found for 3DCNN are specific to videos while I require code for either a CSV file or various CSV files. I've been unable to find any code that can help me out in this scenario. Can someone please help me out? I have no idea how/where to move forward.

Comment: so what is your question exactly?

Comment: I have a general idea in terms of coding CNN and I'm unable to find a way to code my problem. I don't know how to proceed further. So far, my only progress has been condensing my dataset from multiple CSV files into a single one. I currently don't need a great accuracy CNN, I currently just need some form of code that can run this scenario. I can refine it later.